# Saving checked box to database

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I was following a tutorial on Laracasts which showed you how to implement AngularJS into Laravel via a basic `Todos` list. Now, 90% of what I have done works perfectly fine updating the database accordingly apart from the checkbox section...

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
$scope.remaining = function () {
    var count = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function (todo) {
        count += todo.completed ? 0 : 1;
    });

   return count;
}
```

**For reference:**

I am posting the section of index.php of which this code is related to:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter Todos" ng-model="search">

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos | filter:search">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.completed">
            {{ todo.body }}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

The code above indicates once a checkbox has been ticked, to then show you the remaining unticked count. This works fine on a live basis but doesn't update the completed column from 0 to 1 within the database side.

I'm completely new to this, therefore, my attempts have been rather limited but I have tried things such as `$http.post`

I have referred to Google as much as possible but alas, no such luck!

Comment: You should send the ticked or unticked status of checkbox to backend when call the $http.post()

Comment: I'm that far with the understanding of it as this snippet is one of a few already done. However, with my attempts of doing such a thing causes the page to sometimes not load or function whatsoever.